# How to specify login credentials for Google Play reviewer

Tags: android, google-play

I'm submitting an app to Google Play that requires a user account. I'm assuming the reviewer will need credentials in order to review the app, but I'm not seeing a place to specify those in Google Play Console and I'm not able to find any documentation around it. I've attached a screenshot of the equivalent interface in App Store Connect. How does this work in Google Play? Do we wait for the reviewer to ask for it, or are we supposed to include it somehow in the Android App Bundle?

[image: App Review Information iOS]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The currently selected answer has gotten a little out of date. It's no longer necessary to force your app into the under-13's category thankfully, now you can change credentials from:

<kbd>App Content</kbd> > <kbd>App Access</kbd> > <kbd>Manage</kbd> > <kbd>All or some functionality is restricted</kbd> > <kbd>+ Add new instructions</kbd>

This has a free text field for a human reviewer. Alternatively you can also provide automation credentials for the crawler. Find those at:

<kbd>Pre-launch report</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Test account credentials</kbd> > <kbd>Provide Credentials</kbd>

For the automation you can provide the exact field ID for the bot to enter the creds BUT it only works if you have a username *and* a password. It can't be used for a license key for example.

Comment: I have an Android TV app that requires login credentials. But, the login screen is opened in a browser and I can't provide the resource ID for the username and password input fields. How do I handle this situation for the automated testing?

Comment: I would guess just the first part of my answer as that's read by a human not automated. I can't be certain though, sorry

Answer (score 8):

I figured this out after I had already drafted the question. I figured I would go ahead and submit with an answer in case it helps anyone else.

In Google Play Console, you can provide credentials by going to Store presence > App content. Then go through the "Target audience and content" guide. You can specify your test credentials on step 2. However, here's the part that tripped me up: in order to get to step 2, you must indicate that your app targets children under 13 (otherwise, it will skip step 2). I'm not sure if this is a bug or part of Google's policy, but it seemed odd to me. I'm publishing a business tool that is targeted to professional adults, not children, but adding children to my targeting was the only way to provide the credentials the reviewer will need.

Answer (score 3):

As we have experienced, App review is bit different in Google than Apple.

In our project, same as yours it has a login module which is the passport to the app. 
We have never shared the login credentials to Google but for Apple it was mandatory.

Additionally there have been constant changes happening in Google in terms of app review and app rejection ( *targets children under 13* has been introduced last year i believe).
Google may consider *login details* in future for all the apps but currently its not.