# Should I provide my Google Developer Account credentials to Google Play?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I have an app that contains Firebase Authentication with Google. My app was rejected several times due to the fact that I didn't provide credentials. In the [docs](https://playacademy.exceedlms.com/uploads/resource_courses/targets/1383147/original/index.html?_courseId=480215#/page/64364b14f8b5680805f02776), at the "Login credentials for third-party sites" section they say:

> You need to provide the login credentials to third-party sites or provide other ways to access the app.

It seems like the URL is private so I have added a screenshot:

[image]

So do I need to provide my personal Google account credentials? I have a tone of confidential emails there. Is this a requirement so my gets published?

Comment: Your link goes to a restricted resource.

Comment: @Martheen Sorry for not verifying in the first place. I have added a screenshot. Please take a look.

Comment: Oh, that one is for test accounts, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58843019/how-to-specify-login-credentials-for-google-play-reviewer